# Is there another name for N' (N-bar) constituents?

Tags: nouns, syntactic-analysis

[image: syntax tree: "this piece of pie"; "piece of pie" is a N' broken into N and PP]

In the noun phrase "this piece of pie", is there another (?better) name for the N' (N-bar) constituent "piece of pie"?  I presume it's a phrasal constituent, at least in part, because it can be replaced by a pronoun ("this one")?

Comment: N1 is more appropriately called the 'nominal', i.e. the bit between the NP and the head noun.

Answer (score 5):

Huddleston & Pullum (2002) would call this a **nominal.** (On the other hand, their terminology is rather idiosyncratic.)

Comment: _Nominal_ will do if you need a name. On the other hand, you can call it an NP and call the NP a DP, which also shows the difference in labels, but makes other claims.

Comment: The term 'nominal' is more meaningful than N1.

Comment: But only nominally.